# Multiple models for similar type data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm designing a small app as a way to learn Ruby on Rails which will (hopefully) display network traffic trends. Since the data I'm basing off is quite large (100s of millions of rows), we have three tables which sums up data by hour, by day and by month. I'm curious if the proper approach is to create three models, one for each type of data despite their similarities. It seems to be the way I'm leaning with the understanding I will eventually have to do some refactoring to help eliminate duplicate coding. Just curious if there were any other approaches that could be suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using STI(single table inheritance). Read [How (and When) to Use Single Table Inheritance in Rails](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) for more details.

from the article:

> STI should be considered when dealing with model classes that share much of the same functionality and data fields, but you as the developer may want more granular control over extending or adding to each class individually. Rather than duplicate the code over and over for multiple tables (and not being DRY) or forego the flexibility of adding idiosyncratic functionality or methods, STI permits you to use keep your data in a single table while writing specialized functionality.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the link. I'm curious if there are alternatives to collecting all data in a single table as the STI method outlines. The underlying database will be replicating off a master DB, which could cause some additional work on the db side.

Comment: @Andrew can you explain additional work to be done for STI and not for independent models?

Comment: The tables the models are based off are replicated from another, master database. Using STI appears to want to consolidate all the data in one master table with a TYPE column to distinguish between the types. I would have to replicate the data and then consolidate it into one table.